# Move leading numbers after last character using regular expreession

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to position all leading numbers after the last character between two underscores in a string:

**I have this vector:**

```
have <- c("6ABCD23102019", "3ABCD23102019", "9ABCD23102019", "10ABCD23102019")

[1] "6ABCD23102019" "3ABCD23102019" "9ABCD23102019" "10ABCD23102019"
```

**I would like to get this:**

```
desired <- c("ABCD_6_23102019", "ABCD_3_23102019", "ABCD_9_23102019", "ABCD_10_23102019")

[1] "ABCD_6_23102019" "ABCD_3_23102019" "ABCD_9_23102019" "ABCD_10_23102019"
```

This **6ABCD23102019** should become this **ABCD_6_23102019**

**Background:** Within file renaming and copying maneuvers I need to rename the files.

**I have tried:**

```
library(stringr)
x <- str_sub(have, 1,1)
helper <- str_replace(have, '\\dA', 'A')
result <- str_replace(helper, 'D', 'D_x_')
result

[1] "ABCD_x_23102019" "ABCD_x_23102019" "ABCD_x_23102019" "ABCD_x_23102019"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capture groups to capture the one or more digits at the start (`^`) followed by the upper case letters and then rearrange the backreferences (`\\1`, `\\2`) in reverse order

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(have, "^(\\d+)([A-Z]+)", "\\2_\\1_")
```

-output

```
[1] "ABCD_6_23102019"  "ABCD_3_23102019"  "ABCD_9_23102019"  "ABCD_10_23102019"
```